# What's the best way to group these 5 nearly-duplicate questions together?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, locked-posts, linked-questions

These 5 questions are *nearly* the same:

[Is there a way to automatically remove unused CSS rules when building a Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961550/is-there-a-way-to-automaticly-remove-unused-css-rules-from-production-css-file)

[How to find and remove unused CSS by Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837172/how-to-find-and-remove-unused-css-by-chrome)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977251/how-to-detect-unneeded-css-rules-e-g-with-the-browerss-developer-tools

[How to identify unused CSS definitions from multiple CSS files in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/how-to-identify-unused-css-definitions-from-multiple-css-files-in-a-project)

[How can I find unused images and CSS styles in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website)

**What's the best way to link each one to the 4 others?** (this reminds me of the internet "Webring" era!)

Each of them have interesting answers, and no question / no answer should be deleted (or maybe only mine, the 3rd one).

By the way since these questions don't ask for *third-party* tools, but really built-in Chrome Developer tools, I think they really are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> *if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!*

Note: the lock on [How to identify unused CSS definitions from multiple CSS files in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/how-to-identify-unused-css-definitions-from-multiple-css-files-in-a-project) is really problematic because not only can we not comment on current outdated answers and leave a note for future readers about new solutions, we also can't even vote existing comments. I think it should be re-opened, or at least, closed by not locked.

PS: all these questions show that this CSS / programming issue is really a common one, and should be addressed somewhere (ideally in a good canonical question+answer), rather than closed / locked everywhere.

Comment: iof there isn't a canonivcal question make one, and add all valid amswers with lonks to the orignals and then close all other as duplocates

Comment: @nbk The fourth would be the best candidate as "canonical" but it is closed / locked, no longer accepting any interaction... so this is problematic

Comment: Since Chrome cannot delete these rules from a CSS file I would argue that a 3rd party tool is required and so this is a recommendation request. Or else the answer is a simple "You can't".

Comment: You can make a question a duplicate of a locked question, @Basj .

Comment: @Larnu Yes, but this doesn't make any sense *in this specific case*: the target question doesn't accept any interaction, not even a comment on answers like "This is outdated, now use this instead: ...". Here it would be super inefficient in this specific context.

Comment: I must ask, if the question is off-topic do we *want* a canonical duplicate? You say that [How to identify unused CSS definitions from multiple CSS files in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135657) is the best target, but as it's locked it shouldn't be, but said question is off-topic, so making a canonical question for an off-topic subject feels wrong. It would be better to create a canonical duplicate on a site within the community where the question is on topic (if such a community exists). The fact that many people have asked the same off-topic question does not make it on-topic.

Comment: @Larnu It's not off-topic since it doesn't ask about third-party tools/libraries, here it's about Chrome Developer Tools. As mentioned here in my meta question: `if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!`

Comment: Then why is [How to identify unused CSS definitions from multiple CSS files in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135657) closed as off-topic, @Basj ? Perhaps what you are really asking for here is that said question be unlocked (and not closed) so that it can be the canonical duplicate?

Comment: @Larnu I think it's an example of bad closing / locking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic shows it well in this example.

Comment: Which just cements my point. You say that [How to identify unused CSS definitions from multiple CSS files in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135657) is a good canonical target, but because it's locked it can't be. So instead of posting a new canonical version of a question that is *currently* marked as off-topic, get the one you think is a good candidate unlocked. If the question gets unlocked, you get the result you want, if it's refused because it's off-topic then then your suggestion is also refused, as we should not be making duplicates of off-topic questions.

Comment: I can kind of see why that page is locked. The answer would have been useful over a decade ago, but in today's climate... no not really. That audit tool can't audit pages influenced by javascript on the go.

Comment: @Gimby I just spent a 1 hour using this tool, and it's still very useful, it helped me trim my CSS by more than 80% (I did carefully, checking responsiveness, etc.). The website I used has no JS (yes it still exists) except for basic user interaction.

Comment: @Larnu There's no issue with using locked questions as dupe targets

Comment: I never said there was, @TylerH . I explicitly [stated you *can*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415800/whats-the-best-way-to-group-these-5-nearly-duplicate-questions-together?noredirect=1#comment893397_415800)... it was the OP that was against it.

Comment: @Larnu I see, the "*You say that How to identify unused CSS definitions from multiple CSS files in a project is the best target, but as it's locked it shouldn't be*" bit was unclear from your comment above. Sorry!

Comment: Yes @TylerH I was the one :) who said having a dupe target which is locked is not optimal: sometimes impossible to vote up/down, impossible to leave a note as a comment, impossible to post new answers if better methods are available, etc.

Comment: @Paulie_D Technically, Chrome can remove them, if you map the source files (i.e., the files loaded over HTTP) to files in a "workspace". See the Filesystem tab in the left-hand tabset under Sources. It requires a close coupling between the file loaded in the browser and the file in the filesystem, so it's rarely used (by me, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I missed this. I have closed them all as duplicates of their appropriate targets. One was VS-specific, but the rest are duplicates of the two typical canonicals:

- [Optimization- Is there any way to find and remove unused CSS and Javascript common to all html pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497156/optimization-is-there-any-way-to-find-and-remove-unused-css-and-javascript-comm)
- [How to identify unused CSS definitions from multiple CSS files in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/how-to-identify-unused-css-definitions-from-multiple-css-files-in-a-project)

Note that the solution covered here, to use Chrome Dev Tools, *does* include instructions on removing the unused styles, not just identifying them.

Comment: Thanks @TylerH! PS: can you give a link to the precise answer which gives instructions about how to *remove* the unused styles with ChromeDevTools, and not just identify them in green/red? I have read all these questions/answers many times, but maybe I didn't see this specific part precisely :)

Comment: @Basj The top answer on both of them https://stackoverflow.com/a/3113120/2756409 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28497292/2756409

Comment: Oh I see @TylerH, you speak about `Remove unused CSS rules`? I also thought it would be a clickable button that would *do the work*, but in fact it's just an advice for the developer :) and it doesn't do the processing, it's just a text advice.

Comment: @Basj Some of the answers there provide tool recommendations to do that for you, but if you are interested in specifically asking for such a tool that does that, that is off-topic... I think you and Larnu have already discussed *that* ad nauseum in the comments above.

Comment: This is already solved indeed @TylerH.